# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: .filter is not a function . trying to fetch data from json file

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I want to filter the names of nobel prize winners from the following json file:

```
{
     "prizes":[
         {"year":"2018","category":"physics","overallMotivation":"\u201cfor groundbreaking inventions in the field of laser physics\u201d","laureates":[{"id":"960","firstname":"Arthur","surname":"Ashkin","motivation":"\"for the optical tweezers and their application to biological systems\"","share":"2"},{"id":"961","firstname":"G\u00e9rard","surname":"Mourou","motivation":"\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"","share":"4"},{"id":"962","firstname":"Donna","surname":"Strickland","motivation":"\"for their method of generating high-intensity, ultra-short optical pulses\"","share":"4"}]},{"year":"2018","category":"chemistry","laureates":[{"id":"963","firstname":"Frances H.","surname":"Arnold","motivation":"\"for the directed evolution of enzymes\"","share":"2"},{"id":"964","firstname":"George P.","surname":"Smith","motivation":"\"for the phage display of peptides and antibodies\"","share":"4"},{"id":"965","firstname":"Sir Gregory P.","surname":"Winter","motivation":"\"for the phage display of peptides and antibodies\"","share":"4"}]},{"year":"2018","category":"medicine","laureates":[{"id":"958","firstname":"James P.","surname":"Allison","motivation":"\"for their discovery of cancer therapy by inhibition of negative immune regulation\"","share":"2"},{"id":"959","firstname":"Tasuku","surname":"Honjo","motivation":"\"for their discovery of cancer therapy by inhibition of negative immune regulation\"","share":"2"}]},{"year":"2018","category":"peace","laureates":[{"id":"966","firstname":"Denis","surname":"Mukwege","motivation":"\"for their efforts to end the use of sexual violence as a weapon of war and armed conflict\"","share":"2"},{"id":"967","firstname":"Nadia","surname":"Murad","motivation":"\"for their efforts to end the use of sexual violence as a weapon of war and armed conflict\"","share":"2"}]},{"year":"2018","category":"economics","laureates":[{"id":"968","firstname":"William D.","surname":"Nordhaus","motivation":"\"for integrating climate change into long-run macroeconomic analysis\"","share":"2"},{"id":"969","firstname":"Paul M.","surname":"Romer","motivation":"\"for integrating technological innovations into long-run macroeconomic analysis\"","share":"2"}]},{"year":"2017","category":"physics","laureates":[{"id":"941","firstname":"Rainer","surname":"Weiss","motivation":"\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"","share":"2"},{"id":"942","firstname":"Barry C.","surname":"Barish","motivation":"\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"","share":"4"},{"id":"943","firstname":"Kip S.","surname":"Thorne","motivation":"\"for decisive contributions to the LIGO detector and the observation of gravitational waves\"","share":"4"}]},{"year":"2017","category":"chemistry","laureates":[{"id":"944","firstname":"Jacques","surname":"Dubochet","motivation":"\"for developing cryo-electron microscopy for the high-resolution structure determination of biomolecules in solution\"","share":"3"},{"id":"945","firstname":"Joachim","surname":"Frank","motivation":"\"for developing cryo-electron microscopy for the high-resolution structure determination of biomolecules in solution\"","share":"3"}]}
```

Here is my Javascript file:

```js
const search = document.getElementById('search');
const matchlist = document.getElementById('match-List');

//search names.json and filter
const searchName = async searchText => {
const res = await fetch('../data/prize.json');
const names = await res.json();

//get matches to current text input
const matching = names.filter(data => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`,'gi');
    return data.firstname.match(regex);
 });
console.log(matching);



 };

 search.addEventLi`enter code here`stener('keyup', () => 
 searchName(search.value));
```

After running the code it says names.filter is not a function. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` only on arrays. Your data isn't an array.